# Data Cleanup for Regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression, data-cleaning

I have a simple dataset of 1 output and 1 input and want to fit a linear regression to the dataset.
The data has a certain level of noise to it (potentially driven by another input, which I will analyse at a later point). For a given input I have multiple output values associated to it: say the input is 20%, there will be associated outputs of 200, 199, 203, 202, 198 and so on.

Obviously, I will deduplicate my data, but how do I treat this (what I think is) noise. Do I average for every output, before fitting the regression, do I just leave the noise as is or do I do something entirely else?

The screenshot below illustrates what I am talking about: how do I treat the vertical lines? The scatter around it are most likely outliers, due to the nature of the process that is measured.

[image: Plotted data]

Comment: Unless the data is wrong you should not remove it. Are the vertical lines data points or did you add them? Also why is the first line horizontal? If they are data then it looks like there are 2 or more processes generating this data, one generating vertical lines at regular intervals and another generating much more dispersed data. If these lines make sense to you and you can model them with some additional variables, you should include them.

Comment: The vertical lines are the data points I was trying to explain in the text. I was not arguing to remove them, just wondering if summarising each 'vertical line' into an average would be considered good a or bad. The horizontal line in the beginning are mostly bad data.

Comment: Removing data or averaging it essentially has the same effect, you should not remove data or average it (unless it's wrong). If the vertical lines are data and they are the expected output, while the points around them are "weird", you can just fit a model on this data as is, as the model will find the average line going through them, no need to average the data beforehand. A different question is why you have this "weird" data and can you explain it, maybe with some additional variable?

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification! 
The weird data could come from temperature and atmospheric pressure changes, which have a proven effect on the graph above, but my gut feeling says not to that extent. I have not monitored those two variables, but plan on doing that for the next batch. Right now I am trying to see how accurate my regression can be using this  over-simplified approach.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this - I've done some more reading and would just like to hear your take on deduplication? The above data is recorded every minute and logs a valve opening position (X) vs. power output of the system (Y). For that case, do you still stick to your statement of 'unless it is wrong, don't remove it'?

Comment: I don't understand your point, why does this change anything?